# Custom-taxonomy, only one term selectable

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Working with Wordpress 5.1. I'm currently using custom taxonomy with custom post-type. And I'd like to force only one term selectable which is not possible by default with taxonomies. And if possible, I'd like to avoid to use custom-field to make what I aim to conserve the power a taxonomy.

I've found a library (https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Taxonomy_Single_Term) that would make it possible.

But I encounter troubles when I initialize the class, the display of all my metaboxes disappear.

```
include "class.taxonomy-single-term.php";

// Register Taxonomy Type d'activité
function create_typeactivite_tax() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( "Type d'activité", 'taxonomy general name', 'custom-taxonomies' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( "Type d'activité", 'taxonomy singular name', 'custom-taxonomies' ),
        'search_items'      => __( "Rechercher dans les types d'activité", "custom-taxonomies" ),
        'all_items'         => __( "Tous les Types d'activité", 'custom-taxonomies' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( "Type d'activité parent", "custom-taxonomies" ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( "Type d'activité parent:", "custom-taxonomies" ),
        'edit_item'         => __( "Editer le Type d'activité", 'custom-taxonomies' ),
        'update_item'       => __( "Mettre à jour le type d'activité", "custom-taxonomies" ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( "Ajouter un nouveau type d'activité", "custom-taxonomies" ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( "Nouvelle type d'activité", "custom-taxonomies" ),
        'menu_name'         => __( "Catégories principales", "custom-taxonomies" ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( '', 'custom-taxonomies' ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'type-activite', array('activites'), $args );

    // Initialization of class /!\ 
    $custom_tax_mb = new Taxonomy_Single_Term( 'type-activite', array('activites'));
    // Makes a selection required.
    $custom_tax_mb->set( 'force_selection', true );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_typeactivite_tax' );
```

However, it shouldn't really be a big deal to integrate this lib. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "encountering troubles"? That doesn't give us any information about what the problem is, and we can't help you fix it if you don't tell us exactly whats going wrong :)

Comment: In fact, it's a kind of visual bug. It makes two problems :
   1. All the content of the metabox of the concerned taxonomy disappear. It remains only the title of the metabox. 
   2. And all the others metaboxes disappears as well. But entirely, completely disappar from the dom. (except if I add this line of code  `$custom_tax_mb->set( 'priority', 'low' );`) It puts the concerned metabox under the others. 

Real strange behaviour. It sems like a incomptatibility between this lib and this version of wordpress.